# Crystal Reports multiple parameter screens

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

I am creating a report with crystal reports 2008. My report has 4 parameters that the user must input, lets say: var1, var2, var3, var4. When I open the report it brings up the prompt to enter var1, once entered the user clicks next, and it goes to a second screen to get the next parameter, and so on.

My question is, is there a way to combine all of these to one screen. When the report opens, it has 4 drop downs for the parameters instead of one at a time?

I have thought about (and tried) a parameter that accepts multiple values but could not get it to work for my purposes. I am displaying approx 6 fields related to each parameter selected. SO if var1 is entered there will be 6 additional fields displayed. If it is not selected the area remains empty. Essentially each parameter represents a column to display in the report.

If there is a way to combine the 4 parameter screens that would be great, if you think this can be done using a multi value parameter then that is all I need to know and I will keep at it.

Thank you

Comment: Are 4 parameters interlinked?

Comment: Normally it will show all parameter in one display, are you using subreport?

Answer (score 0):

Probably did not go about this in the best way but it serves its purpose and thought I would share for future reference. In response to the comments above, the parameters are not linked and I was not using a sub-report.

I ended up splitting the GroupSectionHEader into 4 parts, one for each variable. The report not contained GroupSectonHeader1-5. Each parameter variable had its own section. The user could select the parameter or False from the parameter input dialog. I then used the section expert and for each Group Header  in the formula box nex to Suppress (No-Drill-Down) entered isnull({@var#}) or {var#} = " " this is because my variables are strings. This way if the user chose False, the variable would be left black and this formula would pick up on that and hide that section in the final formula.

I am very new at CR so I doubt my explanation is as clear as it could be, nor the most proficient.